# Import JavaScript function into html

Tags: javascript, html, function, import

How I can import my function from JavaScript file into html for further use in the html script?

**JavaScript file:**

```
export function test() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="module" src = "script.js">
    test();    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need an import in your main script. Note, that JS modules only work on a web server they do not work locally

Answer (score 1):

Import it this way

```
<script type="module">

import { test } from "./script.js";

test();

</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

If you use

```
<script>

</script>
```

and put your JavaScript inbetween the two that should work